# Как открыть картинку в Picture, WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf

```
private void открытьToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    openFileDialog1.Multiselect = true;
    openFileDialog1.Filter = "Image files (*.BMP, *.JPG, *.GIF, *.TIF, *.PNG, *.ICO, *.EMF, *.WMF)|*.bmp;*.jpg;*.gif; *.tif; *.png; *.ico; *.emf; *.wmf";
    if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        System.IO.FileStream fs = new System.IO.FileStream(openFileDialog1.FileName, System.IO.FileMode.Open);
        System.Drawing.Image img = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(fs);
        fs.Close();
        pictureBox1.Image = img;
    }
}
```

Делала в Windows Forms. C wpf только знакомлюсь. Подскажите как открыть изображение в Picture (WPF) и чтоб оно маштабировалось под окно приложения?

Comment: Ну вы же открыли уже, правильно?

Comment: код не работает в wpf

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам нужно использовать контрол `Image`.

Покажу на примере с кнопкой, при нажатии на которую открывается `OpenFileDialog`. После выбора файла картинки - она показывается в этом контроле.

Пример кода:

CODE

```
// Создадим класс для реализации интерфейса ICommand
// Чтобы использовать его в XAML'е
public class Command : ICommand {
    public Command(Action action) {
        this.action = action;
    }

    Action action;

    EventHandler canExecuteChanged;
    event EventHandler ICommand.CanExecuteChanged {
        add { canExecuteChanged += value; }
        remove { canExecuteChanged -= value; }
    }

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter) {
        return true;
    }

    public void Execute(object parameter) {
        action();
    }
}

// В классе Content реализуем интерфейс INotifyPropertyChanged
// Чтобы послать нотификацию о том, что свойство Image поменялось
public class Content : INotifyPropertyChanged {
    public Content() {
        // Инициализация команды
        openFileDialogCommand = new Command(ExecuteOpenFileDialog);
        // Инициализация OpenFileDialog
        openFileDialog = new OpenFileDialog() {
            Multiselect = true,
            Filter = "Image files (*.BMP, *.JPG, *.GIF, *.TIF, *.PNG, *.ICO, *.EMF, *.WMF)|*.bmp;*.jpg;*.gif; *.tif; *.png; *.ico; *.emf; *.wmf"
        };
    }

    readonly OpenFileDialog openFileDialog;

    // Наша картинка
    public ImageSource Image { get; private set; }

    readonly ICommand openFileDialogCommand;
    public ICommand OpenFileDialogCommand { get { return openFileDialogCommand; } }

    // Действие при нажатии на кнопку "Open File Dialog"
    void ExecuteOpenFileDialog() {
        if(openFileDialog.ShowDialog() == true) {
            using(var stream = new FileStream(openFileDialog.FileName, FileMode.Open)) {
                Image = BitmapFrame.Create(stream, BitmapCreateOptions.None, BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad);
                RaisePropertyChanged("Image");
            }
        }
    }

    // Реализация интерфейса INotifyPropertyChanged
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName) {
        if(PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}

public partial class MainWindow : Window {
    public MainWindow() {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = new Content();
    }
}
```

XAML

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Image Source="{Binding Image, Mode=OneWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
    <Button Grid.Row="1" Command="{Binding OpenFileDialogCommand}" Content="Open File Dialog" />
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 2):

Попробуем чуть проще

XAML:

```
<Image x:Name="img1" Stretch="Fill"/>
<Button Content="" x:Name="buttonOpen" Click="buttonOpen_Click"/>
```

C#:

```
OpenFileDialog openDialog = new OpenFileDialog();
openDialog.Filter = "Image files (*.BMP, *.JPG, *.GIF, *.TIF, *.PNG, *.ICO, *.EMF, *.WMF)|*.bmp;*.jpg;*.gif; *.tif; *.png; *.ico; *.emf; *.wmf";

if (openDialog.ShowDialog() == ModalResult.Ok)
{
  img1.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(openDialog.FileName));
}
```